# Memory Management in C - Allocation of memory slots

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Dear Stack Overflow Family - Happy Near Year  !!! Have all a wonderful time.

I need help to learn memory management in C (and perhaps in general computing). Some book references would be great. All questions below are specific to C Programming.

1. Are the memory addresses assigned during compilation or execution? I have an impression that
   even though the addressed are assigned during execution, the sizes and offsets are defined during compilation. Your comments are much appreciated.
2. Another specific case on above question - say we define a char array. For this data type we just access the array using pointer to the first element. I need to identify for myself - is the pointer the only source required to retrieve the data (all elements of the array) - i.e. when we try to read the array, we just access the first element, and read until we reach the first null character? Or maybe there's a separate register showing the array length so we know where to stop. Again is it defined in compilation or execution?
3. In Addition to above, I assume we really use a register to record used memory slots - so when we define next data type we need to know which slots are free.
   Just need some guidance, or maybe some references, books on this.

Thanks in advance,
Mehdi

No specific problems - just need advice.

Comment: (1) Both. Static variables are allocated statically; dynamic variables dynamically. (2) There is no register containing the length. The compiler knows it (`sizeof`), but if you pass it as a parameter the information is lost. (3) 'Used memory slots' is not a thing in C.

Comment: It will be good if you try to learn assembler first. It will help you to understand many things for pointers, addresses, etc. in C.

Comment: @i486 - thanks. can you pls recommend any sources?

Comment: Rather than assembler I suggest you learn about the three memory areas: (1) static (2) stack (3) heap. There are others but they're not needed to answer your question.

Comment: @MehdiZeynalov Not sure for exact source. You can try this: https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html It is for 32-bit CPU which is simple and more appropriate for beginner. If you know and understand assembly language, you will easily imagine what happens in C and why.

Comment: "*Are the memory addresses assigned during compilation or execution?*" -- the language spec does not say.  In practice, some addresses need to be assigned during execution, but others can be assigned during program loading or even during compilation and linking.  Different C implementations can, and historically have, behaved somewhat differently in this respect.

Comment: Arrays: C does not provide any introspection mechanism.  You cannot compute the length of a declared array at runtime. That information is available at compile time within the scope of the array declaration, but if it is needed outside that scope then it must be conveyed explicitly, either by including a sentinel value in the array, as C strings do, or by specifying the length explicitly as a separate item.

Comment: "*Memory slots*" -- I have no idea what you mean, especially inasmuch as you suppose that whatever they are, they would need to be tracked via a register.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - regarding allocation. Say we define a char array of 2 items. Then we overwrite this at runtime to have more characters (say using scanf). Now when memory is assigned for other variables - will the address of char array + 3 bytes be used, or how is the next address identified?

Comment: We *can't* 'overwrite this at runtime to have more characters (say using `scanf`). The array of 2 items remains an array of 2 items. `scanf()` cannot change that. Nor in fact can anything else.

Comment: @user207421 - does it mean that the memory is allocated at compile time?

Comment: No, it means what it says: there are at least 3 kinds of memory you need to learn about. I don't know what's unclear about that.

Comment: @user207421 - this expression you wrote was un clear - "The array of 2 items remains an array of 2 items. scanf() cannot change that. Nor in fact can anything else." - I read this as array of 2 items is defined in compile time, and thus nothing can change that, so I was asking clarification if it's defined during compilation.

Comment: @MehdiZeynalov, supposing that the array is not allocated dynamically, that it *will be* an array of 2 items is determined at compile time.  When it actually has space and an address reserved for it (is allocated) depends in part on its storage duration and in part on the details of the C language implementation in use.  Once it is allocated, its address, size, and declared data type are are fundamental characteristics of that object -- they do not change during its lifetime.  If you try to use the object inconsistently with those properties then undefined behavior results.

Comment: *Of course* it’s defined during compilation, and where you got the idea that `scant()` can change it remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memories are allocated statically for this code `char c[2] = { 'c', 'q'};`
But,
`char* c = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);`is allocated dynamically.
and here is how you iterate over string literals in C

```
char str[] = "example";
char *ptr = str;
while(*ptr != '\0') { // *ptr dereferences the pointer
    printf("%c", *ptr); 
    ptr++; 
}
```

Memory allocation: The compiler doesn't use a register to track free/used memory slots. Memory management is done at runtime.
For dynamic allocation, functions like malloc() and free() are used to request and release memory.
Static/local variables' memory is managed automatically - allocated when in scope and freed when out of scope.